# Как расставить знаки препинания в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

> Коротко да ясно потому и прекрасно зато нехорошо

Comment: "Огрызок" оригинальной фразы (см ответ @Sibylla) . Полная бессмыслица.

Answer (score 1):

Полное предложение выглядит так: **Коротко да (=и) ясно, потому и прекрасно, зато нехорошо, коль пространно и скучно.**

Союз ДА является соединительным по аналогии со второй частью предложения (пространно и скучно).

Answer (score 0):

Предложение, конечно, странное. Есть два варианта расстановки знаков препинания:

1. Коротко да (=и) ясно, потому и прекрасно, зато нехорошо.
2. Коротко, да (=но) ясно, потому и прекрасно, зато нехорошо.

Всё зависит от того, что значит "да". Мне кажется, более логичным был бы второй вариант.

Comment: Да уж, предложение странное. Хотя бывают и более странные, например "Хуже водки лучше нет" ))) Какие здесь знаки?   
Вот что подумалось: видимо, в некоторых предложениях _не может существовать_ правильной пунктуации, потому что само предложение неправильное.